How to prevent order recreation by user if it doesn't get paid?
when a user creates an order I store it in a database and redirect user to payment platform, but if user doesn't complete purchase and returns to the the website and creates a new order it gets stored as well. So in theory 100 unpaid orders could get stored.
I was asked to make that only one unpaid order be stored by user. There is no user login needed for creating an order.
I'm thinking of storing session token in order and deleting it once order is completed, but I don't know if this is a correct way to go?


I was asked to make that only one unpaid order be stored by user.
There is no user login needed for creating an order.

That requirement to the letter cannot be implemented: we can certainly achieve the goal of at most one "draft" order per authenticated user, but, as you mention, we can only do the same web-session-wise for anonymous users, and of course there are so many ways that an anonymous user can create arbitrary independent sessions.
One could think of tracking IP addresses and/or using cookies for more granularity: but I'd advice against that and similar strengthening for at least two reasons: 1) it gets more and more complicated (and fragile!) and we still cannot fully achieve the goal; 2) usually messing up with the natural flow of these interfaces only bothers legitimate users and impinges on unforeseen but legitimate use cases, on the other hand e.g. a DoS attack remains as easy as it can be.
Overall, beside what can be achieved session-wise, I would advice for what I think is the canonical solution to close that scenario, which is to have a job scheduled server-side that prunes "draft" orders that are older than a certain set period.  (While, if DoS is really a concern, that should be addressed in its own rights and terms.)

FYI the question is off-topic (it's opinion-based, without any code/data (no [mcve]), only a broad description. Please don't answer open-ended question (plus what you posted is more of a discussion response)

@DavidMakogon But we have tags/topics about architecture, design, modelling, patterns: and I do not so much disagree about "code", but those, the proper ones, are all coding question, just not all "code" is textual and implementative, e.g. a diagram is a piece of code, but even a conceptual analysis is, in so far as it is an actual software deliverable.  E.g. in this Q&A we have discussed a precise technical solution to a precise technical problem: we just haven't attached diagrams or scripts or bulleted it, still this is all programming in the strict sense.  --  Anyway, my opinion.

A conceptual analysis is off-topic here. The key thing is, regardless of it being design/model/pattern-related: it has no detail whatsoever. The OP even mentioned storing data in a database, yet doesn't share anything about that storage. Then they pitched a general idea for a vague requirement, followed by a request for opinion. This entire question is off-topic.
